# MySQL on AWS state=failed

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, instance

I'm using RDS on AWS. I didn't turn automatic back up on.
Since yesterday, my instance is showing state=failed.
I'm no able to see why the state changed and which is the error.

Is there any way to recover the database (without needing a backup)?

Comment: In the interest of not making things worse, your safest option is probably to post on the RDS forum and see if an AWS person will pick it up and give you information on how to proceed.  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=60

Comment: InnoDB should provide point-in-time restoring support even if you don't have automatic backups. It's pretty slow, expect a couple of hours waiting time. If the underlying EBS volume is lost though, this is not going to help.